# Valid to de-reference an integer-as-pointer literal in C

Tags: c, posix, c89

Is it portable/valid C to dereference an integer literal treated as an address? ie, if I want to set a 64-bit value at memory address `0x12345678` to `123`, is the following portable and valid C, at least by C89 standards:

```
*(uint64_t *)(0x12345678) = 123ULL;
```

I see no compiler warnings (tested via `gcc -std=c89 -Wall input.c`), but I recall seeing a question on this topic some time back where a case was made for storing the address in an intermediate variable rather than directly de-referencing an integer literal (which has been cast to a pointer address).

Comment: What do you mean portable? The only time I've done something like this is while programming for an embedded system where I'm sure what I'll find in that address. Other than that there is no portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the address `0x12345678` is valid and has an `uint64_t` object, there's no problem with the cast or directly using an integer. But it may not be valid address in all platforms. So, if you know what you are dealing with, it's fine.

Fixed width types were introduced only in C99. So, I find it paradoxical when you are asking about portability of cast to `uint64_t*` in C89 :)

Comment: Addendum: There is actually no *portable* way to get 64-bit integers in most C89 systems/compilers at all (since `long long` didn't exist back then, and `long` is often 32-bit). Some compilers do extend this via (say) `__int64`, but the same ones typically extend C89 with `<stdint.h>` anyways, so one might as well use that. Or, even more portably: a custom `types.h` that defines `MYuint64` or similar (using `long long`, `<stdint.h>`, `unsigned __int64` or whatever else is available).